# Facebook result.isCancelled always getting true for iOS-8 and for iOS-9 its working fine

Tags: ios, facebook, ios8

Facebook SDK version : 4.10

I am using below code

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Do what you have to do but at the end, instead of 'return true', put :

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

Always getting true

```
if result.isCancelled {
                NSLog("Cancelled")
            }
```

Note: *Problem with iOS-8 only (iOS-9 working fine)*

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm also trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

I found out why it was broken for me. I also use Google/SignIn for authenticating with Google. When I set my cocoapods to `pod 'Google/SignIn', '~> 2.0'` the problem goes away. The problem is that `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` wasn't being called in iOS 8. Please note that this method is deprecated in iOS 9.